# Unit testing redux-saga select

Tags: mocha.js, generator, chai, redux-saga

I have a simple saga of this form:

```
const getAccountDetails = function * () {
   const { url } = yield select(state => state.appConfig)
   const accountDetails = yield call(apiFetchAccountDetails, url)
}
```

I'm trying to write a unit test:

```
describe('getAccountDetails', () => {
    const iterator = getAccountDetails()
    it("should yield an Effect 'select(state=> state.appConfig)'", () => {
       const effect = iterator.next().value
       const expected = select(state => state.appConfig)
       expect(effect).to.deep.eql(expected)
    })
```

This test fails. Although `effect` and `expected` are very similar, they are not identical.

At least one of the differences is buried in `payload.selector.scopes`, where the yielded effect and expected are as follows:

[image: screen shot]

As the scopes of these two will always be different, how can these tests ever be made to work?

eta: this pattern is adapted from [the example](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/test/sagas.js) linked to from the redux-saga docs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cracked it after finding [this issue](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/325) from way back.

The fix is to create a named function to do the select and export it from the module where the saga under test lives, and then use this same function in tests. All is well.

```
export const selectAppConfig = state => state.appConfig

const getAccountDetails = function * () {
   const { url } = yield select(selectAppConfig)
   const accountDetails = yield call(apiFetchAccountDetails, url)
}
```

```
    import {selectAppConfig} from './sagaToTest'

    describe('getAccountDetails', () => {
        const iterator = getAccountDetails()
        it("should yield an Effect 'select(state=> state.appConfig)'", () => {
           const effect = iterator.next().value
           const expected = select(selectAppConfig)
           expect(effect).to.deep.eql(expected)
    })
```